Nvidia GPU does not work with Wayland in Ubuntu 22.04.4
My computer (Acer Nitro N50-650 with Ubuntu 22.04.4 can't run wayland with Nvidia, but Xorg does.

GPU: GeForce RTX 3050 OEM
Drivers: NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-535 (private, tested)

I use Ubuntu 22.04.4 Wayland with an Nvidia GPU without any major issues. What exactly doesn't work?

Hi Jaydin. I'm sorry because maybe I can´t explain myself in English and specially about computer things... In the screenshot I added, look like my computer is using llvmpipe instead of Nvidia GPU.

Type these two commands into a terminal and post the results:
mokutil --sb-state and lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'. The first command shows whether secure boot is disabled and the second command shows whether the nvidia driver is installed.

Hello there again. Thanks for your answer.
With the first commans I have the next answer:
SecureBoot enabled.
With the second one, I have:
0000:01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2508 (rev a1)
Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Device a630
Kernel driver in use: nouveau
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

I suspect the problem is having SecureBoot enabled. I had to disable my SecureBoot to get the Nvidia drivers working. Try disabling secureboot by going into UEFI/Bios at boot.

I read something related to that in a forum, but not all the people was agree with that. Anyway I will try to learn how to do that. Thank you for your time and your patience :)

LLVM is the backup graphics driver when the preferred graphics driver (e.g. Nvidia proprietary drivers or Nouveau open source driver) fails for some reason.
One of the common reasons why Nvidia drivers fail is due to SecureBoot being enabled in your PC's UEFI (BIOS). I believe it is trickier to get Nvidia drivers to work with SecureBoot because those drivers need to be signed.
Test to see secure boot is enabled:

Open a terminal
type mokutil --sb-state

If the output is SecureBoot enabled, then first try disabling secure boot in UEFI settings. The process for accessing UEFI settings depend on your system so you may need to check your manual. These askUbuntu answers might help.
It is also possible to use Nvidia drivers with SecureBoot if you follow official Ubuntu instructions. However, I usually found this to be not worth my effort.

sudo apt install libnvidia-egl-wayland1

This package is not installed along nvidia driver by default for some reason

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

So there is a driver issue.
I don't see how people with Ubuntu, or anyone in this thread can help you. Especially given you provide no information except "it does not work".
Try writing in some of the forums for the developers behind your GPU drivers, or stick with XOrg, that seems to work better with your GPU.
